# Getting a powerset recursively

Tags: java, recursion, set, powerset

I want to preface this by saying that this is for a school assignment, so while I want help, it would definitely be preferable to point me in the right direction rather than giving me code to use.

So the assignment is to be able to print out the PowerSet (set of all subsets of a given set) of any given set. I'm moderatly experienced with Java, but recursion is one of my weak points so I'm having trouble visualizing this.

My method returns all subsets which include 'd' and the empty set.

Here's what I have so far:

```
public static TreeSet<TreeSet<Character>> powerSet(TreeSet<Character> setIn) 
{
    Comparator<TreeSet<Character>> comp = new Comparator<TreeSet<Character>>() 
    {
        @Override
        public int compare(TreeSet<Character> a, TreeSet<Character> b)
        {
            return a.size() - b.size();
        }

    };          
    TreeSet<TreeSet<Character>> temp = new TreeSet<TreeSet<Character>>(comp);                                                                               

    if (setIn.isEmpty()) 
    {
        temp.add(new TreeSet<Character>());
        return temp;
    }

    Character first = setIn.first();
    msg(first);
    setIn.remove(first);
    TreeSet<TreeSet<Character>> setA = powerSet(setIn);
    temp.addAll(setA);  
    for (TreeSet<Character> prox : setA) 
    {
        TreeSet<Character> setB = new TreeSet<Character>(prox);
        setB.add(first);
        temp.add(setB); 
    }
    return temp;
}
```

Given the set

```
[a, b, c, d]
```

this method gives me the set

```
[[], [d], [c, d], [b, c, d], [a, b, c, d]]
```

but we know that the PowerSet should be

```
[[], [a], [b], [c], [d], [a, b], [a, c], [a, d], [b, c], [b, d], [c, d],
 [a, b, c], [a, b, d], [a, c, d], [b, c, d], [a, b, c, d]]
```

Any help going in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**: My problem was a really stupid problem. I forget to properly set up the comparator and it was precluding results. I fixed the comparator to sort correctly without throwing away sets.

Here it is:

```
  public int compare(TreeSet<Character> a, TreeSet<Character> b)
            {           
                if(a.equals(b))
                    return 0;

                if(a.size() > b.size())
                    return 1;

                return -1;
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EXTENSIVE EDIT:

The solution is much simpler than I initially thought. You are doing everything very well except the following: before removing the first element from the set, add the set to the `temp` set.

Something like this:

```
 temp.add(setIn);
 Character first = setIn.first();
 msg(first);
 setIn.remove(first);
```

Comment: But if you look at the algorithm given here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set#Algorithms , you only need to remove any one specific element (here, there 1st one), and find the power set recursively of the remaining set.

Comment: I've been trying to accomplish this, but for whatever reason I'm having trouble visualizing how to do this. 

My attempts at using a loop, (probably a terrible idea) have all ended in a stack overflow.

`Character first = setIn.first();
      TreeSet<TreeSet<Character>> setA = null;
      for(int x = 0; x < setIn.size() - 1; x++)
      {
       setA = powerSet(setIn);
       setA.remove(first);
      }`

Comment: It ends up in a stack overflow because the stop condition (which is, the set is empty) is never met; you are calling the method recursively with the same set (`setIn`) you have passed as parameter to the current method execution. You only remove an element form that array after the recursive call. Unfortunately, that line is never reached because the recursive calls end up in the stack overflow.

Comment: @slider The algorithm in there says that the way you have to do it is to combine the removed element with all the subsets of the set obtained by removing that element from the initial set. That's correct and it's a better way than the one I proposed. (My variant would lead to duplicated subsets)

Comment: @Caboose I misunderstood your issue. I edited my answer with my improved (read totally different) solution.

Comment: Hey thanks for all of your help, but this solution didn't seem to help. I think the issue may lie in my comparator as messing with it yields more results. It seems that how I have it set up actually precludes some results.

In fact I'm almost positive this has been causing my issues.

Answer (score 0):

it looks good so far.

you're building every possible subset that contains the first element
this can be extended quite simply to do the same for each element of the initial set. just need to do what you're already doing, but for a different element of the initial set.

that should get you a fair bit closer to the powerset.